# Can I auto-scroll when opening a folder?

Tags: nautilus

When I open a folder in the tree pane, I want to display the sub-folders, and am likely to want to see all of them.  I often then want to open a sub-folder and view the folders within that.

What often happens is that part of the list of sub-folders is displayed.  I scroll so I can see them all, select one, and then have to scroll to see all of them...

Is there a way to configure nautilus so that the folder display is scrolled when I open a sub-folder, to enable me to see all the sub-folders - or at least, the first screen of them?

Answer (score 3):

Nautilus does not currently have a way to do this.

From a technical perspective, this actually shouldn't be too hard to implement. [Nautilus uses the GtkTreeView widget](http://developer.gnome.org/doc/whitepapers/nautilus/nautilus-internals.html) to display the file tree, so in a way it already has the ability to [scroll to a specific item in the list](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-scroll-to-cell). The only missing piece is the instruction from Nautilus to tell GtkTreeView to scroll.

The more difficult task is in convincing the GNOME development team that this scrolling behavior will make Nautilus more intuitive for *everyday users*. If you want to pursue this, the first step is to suggest the idea on [Nautilus's Ubuntu Brainstorm page](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/nautilus/). This is the developers' [preferred](http://live.gnome.org/Nautilus/Ideas) means of suggesting ideas that would be quick to program.